# Python XML processing

Tags: python, xml

```
import xml.sax

class MovieHandler( xml.sax.ContentHandler ):
   def __init__(self):
      self.CurrentData = ""
      self.type = ""
      self.format = ""
      self.year = ""
      self.rating = ""
      self.stars = ""
      self.description = ""

   # Call when an element starts
   def startElement(self, tag, attributes):
      self.CurrentData = tag
      if tag == "movie":
         print ("*****Movie*****")
         title = attributes["title"]
         print ("Title:", title)

   # Call when an elements ends
   def endElement(self, tag):
      if self.CurrentData == "type":
         print ("Type:", self.type)
      elif self.CurrentData == "format":
         print ("Format:", self.format)
      elif self.CurrentData == "year":
         print ("Year:", self.year)
      elif self.CurrentData == "rating":
         print ("Rating:", self.rating)
      elif self.CurrentData == "stars":
         print ("Stars:", self.stars)
      elif self.CurrentData == "description":
         print ("Description:", self.description,
      self.CurrentData = "")

   # Call when a character is read
   def characters(self, content):
      if self.CurrentData == "type":
         self.type = content
      elif self.CurrentData == "format":
         self.format = content
      elif self.CurrentData == "year":
         self.year = content
      elif self.CurrentData == "rating":
         self.rating = content
      elif self.CurrentData == "stars":
         self.stars = content
      elif self.CurrentData == "description":
         self.description = content

if ( __name__ == "__main__"):

   # create an XMLReader
   parser = xml.sax.make_parser()
   # turn off namepsaces
   parser.setFeature(xml.sax.handler.feature_namespaces, 0)

   # override the default ContextHandler
   Handler = MovieHandler()
   parser.setContentHandler( Handler )

   parser.parse("movies.xml")
```

Output:

```
File "<ipython-input-3-17fac27d02c1>", line 35
    self.CurrentData = "")
    ^
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

movies.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

-<collection shelf="New Arrivals">


-<movie title="Enemy Behind">

<type>War, Thriller</type>

<format>DVD</format>

<year>2003</year>

<rating>PG</rating>

<stars>10</stars>

<description>Talk about a US-Japan war</description>

</movie>


-<movie title="Transformers">

<type>Anime, Science Fiction</type>

<format>DVD</format>

<year>1989</year>

<rating>R</rating>

<stars>8</stars>

<description>A schientific fiction</description>

</movie>


-<movie title="Trigun">

<type>Anime, Action</type>

<format>DVD</format>

<episodes>4</episodes>

<rating>PG</rating>

<stars>10</stars>

<description>Vash the Stampede!</description>

</movie>


-<movie title="Ishtar">

<type>Comedy</type>

<format>VHS</format>

<rating>PG</rating>

<stars>2</stars>

<description>Viewable boredom</description>

</movie>

</collection>
```

I am new to Python and using Python 3 kernal in Jupyter notebook (Anaconda Distribution). I am getting this error while trying to parse this xml file in Python. It is not taking "self" as a keyword.
Can anyone let me know what mistake am I making here? Also, let me know what this "self.CurrentData" will do?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not `self`, but the assignment in the `print` method.

> print ("Description:", self.description, **self.CurrentData = ""**)

You will have to do this in two lines:

```
print ("Description:", self.description, self.CurrentData)
self.CurrentData = ""
```

Unless you do not want to do an assignment - at least it would be different from all your other if/else blocks.